# how to use breezeJS in asp.net webforms

Tags: breeze, single-page-application

i have been lately read some articles about [BreezeJS](http://www.breezejs.com/). But till now i can't get my head around it.

1. What exactly [BreezeJS](http://www.breezejs.com/) is used for in details with examples not just words?
2. Can i use it in asp.net WebForms(most of tutorials target MVC projects), and if so how can i use it ?
3. Is there any concerns i need to take in consideration before i use it ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to break your first question into two pieces:

**Do you want to build a JavaScript / [Single Page Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)?**

If you want a cross-platform application with a more fluid user experience, or have a need for offline operation, then Single Page Applications may be a good fit for you.

**Why should I use Breeze in a Single Page Application? Can you cite examples?**

John Papa has a great post about this that includes a few examples:
http://www.johnpapa.net/spajs04

You can use WebForms, MVC, or any number of other technologies to build a Single Page Application. For ASP.NET, people typically use MVC4 though. Here is StackOverflow post on that topic that might help:
[webforms vs asp.net mvc for single page application - which to choose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536422/webforms-vs-asp-net-mvc-for-single-page-application-which-to-choose)